# Cannot extract image path from project bundle

Tags: ios, image, swift3, path, bundle

I am trying to get the path to an icon image which is part of the Xcode project, but without luck. I can create an image using the name, but i need the path.

```
let img = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "credit.jpg", ofType:"jpg")

let imm = UIImage(named: "credit.jpg")
```

I can see that img is nil but imm is not.
Any ideas?

Comment: use this  let img = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "credit", ofType:"jpg")
remove ".jpg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Check this:

**For Image Path:**

```
let img = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "credit", ofType: "jpg")
print(img!)
```

**For Image Url:**

```
let img = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "credit", withExtension: "jpg")
print(img!)
```

Comment: I tried that and several other combinations with no better luck.

Comment: pls, remove image extension from the forResource only write image name in it, like my answer.

Comment: That didn't work, but then I tried substituting a different image and it did work, but I can't get it to work with certain files. It must have something to do with how the files get added to the project, but what is still a mystery. I am indicating that the files should be copied.